# Slow dowload speeds on Windows10/11 from HTTP and FTP

Tags: networking, ftp

I have a really weird problem and I have a vague memory that it happened already in the past and I did find a solution but can't recall which one.

Situation: gigabit connection, everything works fine (steam, microsoft store, you name it) all work fine and get very fast download speeds.

FTP (secure or any combination) and HTTP downloads seems to be capped at 250Kb/s.

Running a VPN makes 0 difference. Same connection (even same ethernet cable!) on my Mac do not have this problem at all. Downloading from the same exact FTP results in a fast download.

I tried EVERYTHING and nothing seems to make a difference. I thought updating to Windows 11 would fix it, but no luck.

Before I format and install everything again (which will undoubletly solve the issue) I would like have a reasonable examplanation for this..
It's quite weird!

Any help: appreciated!

Comment: Which software do you use for the downloads? Did you use a different download client already? If you say HTTP downloads, does the same happen when downloading via a webbrowser?

Comment: I use Filezilla, same settings on PC and Mac. Any file downloaded through a browser is capped at 250Kb/s it's so weird.

Comment: You might try a tool such as Free Download Manager, https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/ , which employ multiple parallel "pipes" to download at much higher speed.